# How do I connect to a Mondrian cube(XMLA) using IBM Cognos

Tags: mondrian, cognos-10, xmla

I want to connect to a Mondrian cube that I've developed using IBM Cognos.
On the Cognose framework I can't see the XMLA datasource on the list, the datasource connection should be an ODBO.

How can I made the ODBO connection available?

Regards
Monwabisa

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlaconnect/ works for connecting Excel with Mondrian via ODBO. Maybe it also works for your use case.